# CFHTTP Content-Length Header for post to Google Voice "API"

Tags: coldfusion, railo, google-voice

Greetings.

I'm trying to send a quick sms through google voice using their existing API. I think the api is what's left from the Grand Central days. They don't have much documentation. Here's where I got my documentation: http://posttopic.com/topic/google-voice-add-on-development

I can authenticate using cfhttp and get the correct response. Then I can get the "_rnr_se" value that is required for request from a google voice command.

When I send over the number, message, and required values (Authorization and _rnr_se), I get a "content-length" is required message from google. But since this is a dynamic post with different form fields, not a file, I'm not sure what to post as the content-length.

If I just put some arbitrary value like "1000" for the content-length, the request just sits there and I never get a response. If I put something like "0" or "500" it comes back with a 500 - "Internal Server Error".

**Any ideas on how to get the correct value for content-length before I post?**

```
<cffunction name="submitSMS">

    <cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/voice/sms/send/" method="post">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Length" value="???">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="GoogleLogin auth=#SESSION.GoogleAuth#">
        <cfhttpparam name="id" value="" type="formfield">
        <cfhttpparam name="phoneNumber" value="+1#params.number#" type="formfield">
        <cfhttpparam name="text" value="#params.smsMessage#" type="formfield">
        <cfhttpparam name="_rnr_se" value="#SESSION.rnr#" type="formfield">
    </cfhttp>

    <cfdump var="#cfhttp.FileContent#"><cfabort>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: If you change the form to post to another cf template on your server, and just dump the post (<cfdump var="#getHTTPrequestdata()#" format="text" output="console"> = dumps to cfserver.log), you'll see that its already sending a content-length header.  Oh, wait, are you on Railo?  I'm testing with CF8, so I don't know what Railo does.  But, if you try dumping the post, what do you see?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using Railo. Apparently, Railo doesn't automatically append the content-length header. But, the end result was to use google voice api. There was already a java class wrapper built for this which you can easily access in CF.

Comment: BTW: Are you sure about the Content-Length header and Railo? I could have sworn it does create that header.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do this is to just use the google voice java class here:

http://google-voice-java.googlecode.com