# Using Coldfusion to Programmatically Access the Google Voice Java API

Tags: java, coldfusion, jar, coldfusion-9, google-voice

Can anyone tell me how to use Coldfusion to access and interact with the Google Voice Java API?

1. Specifically how would I access API jar files?
2. How would I programtically access these files/classes via Coldfusion's Java capabilities? For example within a CFC what java classes/functions would I need to call?
3. Even more basic, in which coldfusion folder would the Java API jar need to be installed?

Stackoverflow member [@GuidDoody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282255/guidoody) mentioned he was able to successfully use the Java API with Coldfusion here: [CFHTTP Content-Length Header for post to Google Voice "API"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752588/cfhttp-content-length-header-for-post-to-google-voice-api/3762223#3762223) . However, no details were given as to how!

Alternatively, am I better off just using CFHTTP to "hack" a log-in and data capture sequence programamtically?

Here is are the resources I've searched so far. But I need help on doing steps 1 - 3 above :

1. Google Voice Java API How to: http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/wiki/GettingStarted
2. Java API string value pairs: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=7d165bcdbdba6464&hl=en
3. [@GuidDoody's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282255/guidoody) use of CFHTTP: [CFHTTP Content-Length Header for post to Google Voice "API"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752588/cfhttp-content-length-header-for-post-to-google-voice-api)

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Mark Mandel's JavaLoader is what you are looking for: http://javaloader.riaforge.org/

Here's an example of how I used it to use the Evernote API jar files:

```
//first create an array of locations to your jar files
jarArray = ["#libDirectory#/CFEvernote.jar","#libDirectory#/evernote-api-1.18.jar","#libDirectory#/libthrift.jar"];

//then create an instance of the classloader and pass it your jar array
classLoader = createObject("component", "JavaLoader").init(jarArray );

//then use the classloader.create method to create a new java object
note = classLoader.create("com.evernote.edam.type.Note").init();
```

Comment: The javaLoader is more flexible. But if you wanted you could also throw the jars into the CF class path somewhere, like into `WEB-INF\lib`. Then use createObject("java") instead.